# Javascript and button toggling

Tags: javascript, html

just when I think I've sorted it... a small toggling question - this code is meant to toggle from Play to Stop when clicked, but it doesn't. I can't see any problems with the variables - but then I don't really know js very well. Can anyone see why this doesn't work? Code follows..
    var selSound = 8000; //default to first sound.
    var play = false; //default to paused.

```
function selectSound(id) {
    selSound = id;
}

function togglePlay() {
    var a = document.getElementById(selSound);
    var b = document.getElementById("playbtn");
    play = !play;
    if (play) {
        b.value = "Stop Playing";
        a.play();
    }
    else {
        b.value = "Start Playing";
        a.pause();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center"><button id="playbtn" data-role="button"     onclick="togglePlay()" >Start Playing</button></div>
```

This is part of an iOS/html5 project and will be tested in Safari and iOS simulator.
Thanks
J

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes:

```
var a = document.getElementById(selSound);
```

Should be:

```
var a = document.getElementById('selSound');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `input type="button"`?

```
var play = false;
function togglePlay() {

    var b = document.getElementById("playbtn");
    play = !play;
    if (play) {
        b.value = "Stop Playing";
    }
    else {
        b.value = "Start Playing";

    }
}
```

and html:

```
 <input type="button" id="playbtn" data-role="button" value="Start playing" onclick="togglePlay()" />
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/awetew/2/edit)

**EDIT**

With button you have to use `innerText`

```
var play = false;
function togglePlay() {

    var b = document.getElementById("playbtn");
    play = !play;
    if (play) {
        b.innerText = "Stop Playing";
    }
    else {
        b.innerText = "Start Playing";

    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/awetew/3/edit#source)

Comment: Ah - thank you - that works great but not in html5 - is there a way this could work with JQMobile?
J